# How to set numpy matrix elements to a value with given indexes

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, slice

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour but on a 2D array with no success

```
indices = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
zero = np.zeros(10)
zero[indices] = 42
zero
>>>array([ 0., 42.,  0.,  0., 42., 42., 42., 42.,  0.,  0.])
```

If i try the same with a zeros 5x5 matrix i can't figure out how to do the correct slicing

```
indices = np.array([1,2],[2,4],[3,1])
zero = np.zeros((5,5))
zero[indices] = 42
```

This is my output

```
>>> zero
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., 42.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 42.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 42.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 42.]])
```

My desired would be like:

```
>>> zero
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  42., 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  42.],
       [ 0.,  42.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I have tried slicing like zeros[indices,indices] but i just get to modify the first two elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the two axes ("x" and "y") of your indices separately:

```
indices = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]])
zero = np.zeros((5,5))
zero[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = 42  

>>>zero                                                                                             
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 42.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 42.],
       [ 0., 42.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `zero[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = 42` is very explicit but you can also use `zip` for readability. I.e. `zero[*zip(*indicies)] = 42`. Not a must but definitely nicer to read (for me) :)