# Adding to Random Index

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch

I'm trying to add some value at random indexes in a PIL image. I could do that by

```
#find random row and column indices    
idx_r=random.choices(np.arange(cat[:,0,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
idx_c=random.choices(np.arange(cat[0,:,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[1]*0.25)))
        
#add at those indices        
for i in idx_r:
     for j in idx_c:
           cat[i,j,:] = torch.add(cat[i,j,:], cost)
```

However, it is very time expensive to do that over images of large size. I can't use the normal masking method for mutlidimensional arrays. Is there an computationally easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't really "find random row and column indices". What you are doing is generating an array of size `k` with random elements of `cat[:,0,0]`, not with their indices.
Generating a random arry of indices would be done as follow:

```py
idx_r=random.choices(np.arange(cat[:,0,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
idx_c=random.choices(np.arange(cat[0,:,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
```

Secondly, you should not need `torch.add` here, `cat[i, j, :] = cat[i, j, :] + cost` should have the same effect and might allow you to not import `pytorch`.

**I will leave the rest of the answer here in case it is useful for anyone, but it doesn't seem of any use for the original question in this state.**

Here, I used the answer to [How to set numpy matrix elements to a value with given indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774254/how-to-set-numpy-matrix-elements-to-a-value-with-given-indexes) to do a simple matrix addition.

```py
idx_r=random.choices(np.arange(cat[:,0,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
idx_c=random.choices(np.arange(cat[0,:,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
zeros = np.zeros(cat.shape)
zeros[idx_r[:], idx_c[:], :] = cost
cat = np.add(cat, zeros)
```

After verification, it seems this method is way slower than the original you proposed. So much slower in fact that I would assume it is an error rather than a coherent result:

```py
from timeit import timeit
setup: str = '''
import numpy as np
import random
cat = np.random(500, 500, 500)
idx_r = random.choices(np.arange(cat[:,0,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
idx_c = random.choices(np.arange(cat[0,:,0].shape[0]), k=int((cat.shape[0]*0.25)))
cost = 42
'''
original: str = '''
for i in idx_r:
    for j in idx_c:
        cat[i, j, :] = cat[i, j, :] + cost
'''
mine: str = '''
zeros = np.zeros(cat.shape)
zeros[idx_r[:], idx_c[:], :] = cost
cat = np.add(cat, zeros)
'''
timeit(original, setup=setup, number=100) # 4.27609...
timeit(mine, setup=setup, number=100) # 30.05506...
```

Comment: Agh yes that is indeed incorrect, however as you already mentioned the method is much slower.